# How can I limit memory usage on local run as leetcode requested

Tags: node.js, typescript

I want to limit my memory usage on local run as leetcode requested to debug memory overflow problem.

I tried process.memoryUsage() or --max-old-space-size, but they refer to V8 memory usage, no that "memory limit" on leetcode problem.

Using WebStorm, Nodejs, Typescript, any idea?

Comment: To be clear, are you submitting your answer on leetcode, and it is coming back with "Exceeded memory limits" error on one of the tests?

Comment: Yes and no. in fact I want to optimize the space usage of my algorithm.